# external php script for check ban on mybb users

Tags: php, mybb

guys i need a function to add on my external php script for check ban on mybb users

I want this function check the database if user is banned, return this echo:
 line 1: you are banned from this board
 line 2: ban reason: $banreason
 line 3: ban time: $bantime

look guys i dont programer so i know this code have many problem i just want to show you what i need :

```
<?php
class ban
{
Function check_ban($uid)
{
  $sql = "Select * From mybb_banned ORDER BY dateline DESC LIMIT 30";
  $result=mysql_query($sql);

  if($mybb->user['uid'] = $result2 ['uid'])
    {
     return array( 'banreason' => $result['baneason'] ,
                   'bantime'   => $result[ 'bantime' ],
                 );
    }
 }
}

$result2 = $ban->check_ban( $uid );

if( $result == false )
{
    echo "you are banned\n" ;
    echo $result[ 'banreason' ]."\n" ;
    echo $result[ 'bantime' ] ;
}
?>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the result id to the user id rather than comparing them. Also I think you are mixing up `$result` and `$result2`

The other issue is that you need to loop through all the banned members and check for each

A neater approach would be to do something like this:

```
class ban
{    
    static function check_ban($username)
    {
      // only fetch results for that uid
      $sql = "Select * From mybb_banned INNER JOIN mybb_users ON mybb_banned.uid = mybb_users.uid ORDER BY dateline DESC LIMIT 30 WHERE mybb_users.username=$username";
      $result=mysql_query($sql);

      if(mysql_num_rows($result)) // check if any entries where returned from the database
        {
         return array( 'banreason' => $result['mybb_banned.banreason'] ,
                       'bantime'   => $result[ 'mybb_banned.bantime' ],
                     );
        }
      else return false;
    }
}

if( ban::check_ban( $username ) )
{
    echo "you are banned\n" ;
    echo $result[ 'banreason' ]."\n" ;
    echo $result[ 'bantime' ] ;
}
```

Here, I've made the check_ban method static so you don't need to instantiate an instance of ban before you can use it.

EDIT: I've edited the code above so that it searches based on username by joining the mybb_users and mybb_banned tables (think of it as temporarily combining the two tables into one where the rows are matched using the uid)

Comment: thank you but how to check $uid in mybb because user only use username and password but i need to clear $uid with $username.

Comment: Fatal error: Class name must be a valid object or a string in ... on line 65 .and the line 65 is :  if( $ban::check_ban( $username ) )